# If hours over 24 don't reset

Tags: php, datetime, datetime-format

I currently made a function which tells from timestamp the hours, minutes and seconds left. But when the item is ending in more than 24 hours it should show example 48 hours and not resetting it. How can i do this?

I have days already, but i should be only in hours, minutes and seconds, ex. 
76 hours, 20 minutes & 20 seconds.

```
    $time = strtotime($row['start_date']) - time();

    $days = floor($time / (60 * 60 * 24));
    $time -= $days * (60 * 60 * 24);

    $hours = floor($time / (60 * 60));
    $time -= $hours * (60 * 60);

    $minutes = floor($time / 60);
    $time -= $minutes * 60;

    $seconds = floor($time);
    $time -= $seconds;


    $hours = ($hours<10) ? "0" . $hours : $hours;
    $minutes = ($minutes<10) ? "0" . $minutes : $minutes;
    $seconds = ($seconds<10) ? "0" . $seconds : $seconds;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$days = floor($time / (60 * 60 * 24));
$time -= $days * (60 * 60 * 24);
```

Your code removes the day part from the timestamp, that's why.